# How to get the birthday,country,gender from facebook in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook-graph-api

I am using below code to get user details but it gives me only name,email,id but not giving all profile info.Please tell me how can i get all basic info.

```
- (void)loginButton:    (FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton
didCompleteWithResult:  (FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *)result
error:  (NSError *)error;
{
    NSLog(@"login done");
    NSMutableDictionary* parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [parameters setValue:@"id,name,email" forKey:@"fields"];
    if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken])
    {
        NSLog(@"isndie con");
        [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:parameters]
         startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
         {
             NSLog(@"isndie handler");
             NSLog(@"result is %@",result);
             NSLog(@"error is %@",[error localizedDescription]);

                 NSDictionary *userInfo=result;
                 email=[userInfo objectForKey:@"email"];
                 name=[userInfo objectForKey:@"name"];
             NSString *facebookId=[userInfo objectForKey:@"id"];
              NSString *imageUrl = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"http://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large", facebookId];
             NSLog(@"iamge ur lsi %@",imageUrl);
                // [self isFBLoginFirstTime];

         }];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"no token");
    }
    NSLog(@"end of code");
}
```

Comment: you've to ask for  permission related to field you want!

Answer (score 2):

You can get Date Of Birth, country and gender of login user.

```
[parameters setValue:@"id,name,email,birthday,gender,hometown" forKey:@"fields"];
```

Just modify your params .

You can go through this for other keys .

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user

Comment: Not able to get hometown ,birthday only gender,email,name,id is fetched.

Comment: Then check 1> If for that FB user hometown & birthday has been given in his FB id or not ? 2> If those are given in that ID then check permission for that ID ?

Comment: I have checked birthday & hometown given & it is public .

Comment: then i guess , it should come in the response .

Comment: Try with logging as any other user .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98530/discussion-between-sourav-and-dheeraj-kumar).

Comment: @DheerajKumar have you found a solution?? I cant get birthday either!

Comment: hello i am not getting hometown and country from Facebook can you plz help?